# A number theory question with calculus

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $P(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ Show there exists a non-constant polynomial $m(x)$ such that $m^2(x)|P(x)$ iff gcd$(P(x),P'(x))$ is not $1$.

My attempt: if $m^2(x)|P(x)$ then $m(x)|gcd(P(x),P'(x))$. So the only if part is pretty much done

Help with if part

Comment: Hint: If the gcd is not $1$, consider a common divisor that is irreducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\gcd \ne 1$ then $p(x) =k(x)(x-a)$ and $p'(x) =q(x)(x-a)$ for some $a$. But $$p'(x) = k'(x)(x-a)+k(x)$$

So if we put $x=a$ we get: $$0=p'(a) = k(a)\implies x-a\mid k(x)$$ $$\implies k(x)=r(x)(x-a)$$

so $p(x)= r(x)(x-a)^2$

Comment: Could $gcd(p,p')$ be a quadratic polynomial that is irreducible in $\mathbb R[x]$?

Comment: Say $p(x)=(x^2+1)^2x=(x^4+2x^2+1)x=x^5+2x^3+x$ and then $$p'(x)=5x^4+6x^2+1=(5x^2+1)(x^2+1)$$

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! Nice example.

Comment: So do you have to modify your proof to accommodate this situation?

Comment: Why? First, it is not said that $m(x)$ must be with real coefficents. Second, even so, $x-a'$ divide p(x) so we can repeat procedure with x-a' and take $m(x) =(x-a)(x-a')$ which is irreducibile in real.

Comment: When I attempted the problem, I let $p(x)=d(x)q(x)$ and $p'(x)=d(x)r(x)$ Thanks for your nice insight!